# Xcode Storyboard segue to pass song title from array to detail view controller

Tags: arrays, tableview, segue

I get this error message:-`[MPConcreteMediaItem isEqualToString:]`: unrecognized selector sent to instance…

I am creating an NSMutable array of songs from media picker into an array named "array". This array shows up properly in the tableview (myTable). HOWEVER when I try to segue to the detail view and send the song title to a label on the detail view following this tutorial. I get the crash and error message above.

Appreciate any help, thanks!

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"detailView"]) {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTable indexPathForSelectedRow];

    DetailViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

    vc.trackName = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //crashes -[MPConcreteMediaItem isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

    }

}

- (void)mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection {

    [array addObjectsFromArray:mediaItemCollection.items];

    [myTable reloadData];

    // mediaItemCollection = nil;

    [mediaPicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //this method is called to fill out table with data

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]

    initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault

    reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

}

    // Configure the cell

    anItem = nil;

    anItem = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [anItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error looks like that you aren't calling 'isEqualToString:' on a string object... Which superclass has MPConcreteMediaItem

Comment: Where should I be calling  'isEqualToString:' ? On the trackName = array objectatindex? Sorry I don't understand. Thanks!

Comment: I tried this but may have not been what you meant :vc.trackName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];  --Instead of the song name I got ,MPConcreteMediaItem 0x1fd09830> followed by a string of numbers. Of course I am trying to get the song title from the array on the table view selected row into a label on the detail view. Thanks!

Comment: This solved the problem:                                   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTable indexPathForSelectedRow];
        // Reference to destination view controller
        DetailViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        MPMediaItem *songToPlay = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *titleString = [songToPlay valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
        vc.trackName = titleString;